# Can format string diagnostics be enabled from #pragma in code rather than -Wformat command-line option?

Tags: gcc

The #pragma here doesn't seem to have any effect. The code compiles without any warnings:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wformat"

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i = 5;
        char s[] = "test";

        /* missing argument */
        printf("%s");
        printf("%d %s", i);
        /* missing format specifier */
        printf("%s", s, i);
        /* type mismatch */
        printf("%d", s);
        printf("%s", i);

        return 0;
}
```

There are warnings when using the -Wformat option on the command-line:

```
[user@host test]$ gcc -c test.c
[user@host test]$ gcc -Wformat -c test.c [A
gcc: [A: No such file or directory
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:11: warning: too few arguments for format
test.c:12: warning: too few arguments for format
test.c:14: warning: too many arguments for format
test.c:16: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'
test.c:17: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'
```

It seems if I change the #pragma to make it an error, then it also only has an effect when using the -Wformat command-line parameter:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wformat"
```

So then the output looks like:

```
[user@host test]$ gcc -c test.c
[user@host test]$ gcc -Wformat -c test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:11: error: too few arguments for format
test.c:12: error: too few arguments for format
test.c:14: warning: too many arguments for format
test.c:16: error: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'
test.c:17: error: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'
```

Is there a way to enable format string checking, at all, regardless if making it an error or warning, entirely from C code, and not require the -Wformat command-line parameter?

I share a simple Makefile between Linux and AIX, and it's easier to do conditional compilation purely from code.

Comment: Why don't add these options to your Makefile - it's a common way

Comment: I gave a reason at the end of the question. I'll go that route once I confirm it is not possible from code.

Comment: "I share a simple Makefile between Linux and AIX, and it's easier to do conditional compilation purely from code." - well you have to pass that information from your build tool to the compiler anyway. So there is no problem also to set the `CFLAGS` appropriately. That way your whole code is checked, not just a small portion.